# Sparse columns or normal columns?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have 6 columns of date-time type in a table. My application has a requirement that each column should have additional column one for validation that can be of a bit datatype and another modified date-time if user wants to modify it. So my question is that is there any thing better than adding 2 column for each column I have? Also I know about Sparse columns which I can use to save my table space but still is there any thing better I can do??

**The 'Bit' Logic**

So there are 3 columns

1. original datetime,
2. modified datetime and
3. Validation bit.

Validation bit is by default set to false. When user want to change the date-time then modified date-time column will be updated with new value; however, there will be no change in original date-time column. Now user has to make decision whether value being entered is validated or not. The validation bit will decide this functionality.

Comment: It would help if you explained the logic behind the validation bit...

Comment: @jsobo :So there are 3 column 1. original datetime, 2. modified datetime and 3. Validation bit. Validation bit is by default set to false. When user want to change the date-time then modified date-time column will be updated with new value however there will be no change in original date-time column. Now user has to make decision whether value being entered is validated or not. The validation bit will decide this functionality. Hope this helps.

Comment: Under what conditions would a user enter a date and then decide it is not valid?   I get the sparse columns and that seems like a good use.  I just don't get this validation bit.

Comment: @Blam : there would be a web form having column original date, modify date and is Modified date valid. User sees the original date and then decides whether he wants to change the date or not. If he decides to change then stores a new date in modify date column in form as well as in table. Then user need to decide whether this modified date is valid or not based on business rules. If the modify date is valid then he will select true option which will set validation bit to true otherwise keep it as it is. Hope this helps.

Comment: Then I would change the statement to the validation bit represents the status.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would disable the Valid checkbox until they enter a modified date.  Sparse for those two columns works.

Comment: Thanks @Blam for the answer but I guess I am not able to explain question properly here. I was asking is Sparse column is the only option I have when I have one main column and 2 other column which should be there but will not necessarily be populated every time??

Comment: You could have a separate table with a FK relationship.  In the table the FK would also be the PK so it only has 0 or 1 row for each row the primary table.  A join to a PK clustered index is very fast.   Personally I use that over sparse columns as just a personal preference and prior to 2005 sparse was not available..